# Always have a maximum of 10 values, with the last value being in B1 and the one in A1 disappearing

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I will use a script to copy the data from `Column C` to `Column A`, always adding 1 value that is in `B1` and remove the `A1` value

If I do it this way, there will always be 11 values:

[image]

If I do it this way the value of `B1` will never appear:

[image]

If I do it this way when there are less than 10 values in `Column A` it will never go from row 7 and add up to row 10:

[image]

If I do it this way there will be lines with no values between the data and this cannot happen:

[image]

```
How I wish it were!
```

If there are **less than 10 values** in `Column A`, look like this:

[image]

If there are **10 values** in `Column A`, look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use double reverse ranges and querying non-empties

```
=IF(COUNTA(A:A)>=9,{
    SORT(QUERY(SORT(A:A,ROW(A:A),0),
           "where Col1<>'' limit 9"),
      ROW(A1:A9),0);
    B1
  },
  QUERY({A:A;B1},"where Col1<>''")
)
```

[image]

There is the second solution

```
={IFNA(IF(
  ROWS(A:A)-MATCH("*",SORT(IF(A:A="",,TO_TEXT(A:A)),ROW(A:A),0),0)>=9,
  OFFSET(A:A,ROWS(A:A)-MATCH("*",SORT(IF(A:A="",,TO_TEXT(A:A)),ROW(A:A),0),0)+1-9,0,9),
  OFFSET(A:A,0,0,ROWS(A:A)-MATCH("*",SORT(IF(A:A="",,TO_TEXT(A:A)),ROW(A:A),0),0)+1)
),"");B1}
```

This support empties cells and numbers

[image]

Comment: Hi @contributorpw The limit is 10 cells, cannot exceed that amount.  that's the problem.

Comment: @BrondbyIF, I see. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Hi @contributorpw thanks for listening, the problem now is when we have less than 10 total values ​​in column A, because it is giving an error.

Comment: Maybe add `IF`?

Comment: @BrondbyIF, please, check the second variant if you need blank cells too.

Answer (score 1):

no need to overthink it:

```
=IF(COUNTA(A1:A10)=10, {A2:A10; B1}, {FILTER(A1:A10, A1:A10<>""); B1})
```

[image]